# make deb file and install resulting package

Tags: package-management, deb

I am quite new to Linux and am trying to install Tirex on an Ubuntu server.  Tirex is mapping-related software, and its [instructions](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tirex/Building_and_Installing) indicate that to use it one must "install from source or build your own Debian/Ubuntu packages."

After a fair amount of dependency-related trial and error (mostly), I have managed to get the following commands to execute successfully:  (see above link for more info)

```
make
sudo make install
```

However, after doing that, I am having trouble getting Tirex to run as I expect it might, and I notice on the [instruction](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tirex/Building_and_Installing) page that the Debian/Ubuntu packages will take care of some setup configuration.  This is where I have trouble.

When I run...

```
make deb
```

...it seems to compile okay (a few warnings, but no errors that stop it), but I don't see any .deb packages created.  There are some new directories and files but no .deb files.

**How do I know if `make deb` has been successful, and/or how do I install the results if it has been (and there isn't a .deb file)?**

Comment: You will need to look in the source code directory, build directory, or perhaps one directory up for the .deb . If you can not find it, `sudo updatedb && locate *.deb $HOME`

Comment: Wow, I feel like a prize idiot for not having seen those.  They were in the parent directory, just as the install instructions said they would be.  As I mentioned, I am new to Linux, but I'm not *that* new.  I had been using the "find" command to search for *.deb files.  Evidently I had been misusing it.  @bodhi.zazen if you write an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: It is easy to become frustrated , we have all been there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It varies by developer / source code, but the resulting .deb are often in one of 3 locations, the parent directory, the build directory, or sometimes in a directory within the source code.

If not specified in the README, you can find them with locate or find.

```
sudo updatedb
locate *.deb $HOME
```